# MapStruct implementations not being generated when using `mvn package`

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, mapstruct

Here's to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.17</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                <target>1.17</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                <release>17</release>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.22</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have annotated my classes with `@Mapper`. When I examine the target folder, the mapper implementations are not there. The weird part is, when I compile using IntelliJ's build functionality, the classes are generated and I can see them under the target folder. But when I compile using `mvn clean package` or just `mvn package` the classes are not generated. What can cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue thanks to a user over at GitHub - [issue link](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2647#issuecomment-963155079). The problem was with the 1. prefix in the source and target tags. Apparently, the prefix has been deprecated since Java 9. So I removed it:

```
<source>17</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
<target>17</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
<release>17</release>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of, that slipped my mind the first time I used mapstruct is the classes need to be interfaces, this is a sample class I have that uses mapstruct:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.*;

@Mapper
public interface BeaconMapper {

    public BeaconMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( BeaconMapper.class ); 

    public BeaconDTO BeaconToBeaconDTO( Beacon beacon );
    public Beacon BeaconDTOToBeacon( BeaconDTO beaconDTO );
}
```

I reviewed your pom.xml and I don't see anything wrong with it, so I don't think that is the issue, good luck!

Comment: I am using the annotation on the interfaces. Thanks anyway

Comment: i fixed the issue. you can check out my answer to the question to see how